# Knockout.js, CoffeeScript and jQuery ajax doesn't update text fields

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to receive data via AJAX and show it on the page. The ajax request is successful, but knockout doesn't update view. What can be the problem?

**Source Code: View Model**

```
class AppViewModel
  constructor: ->
    @company = ko.observable {name:'n/a', tariff:'n/a', contract:'n/a', balance:'0'}
    @getBriefInfo()
    @companyTariff = ko.computed  => "Tariff: #{@company.tariff}"
    @companyBalance = ko.computed => "Total: #{@company.balance}"


  getBriefInfo: ->
    $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: '/index.php/site/getCompanyShortInfo'
        data: {}
        dataType: 'json'
        contentType: 'json'
        success: (res) =>
          console.log @company(), res.name, res.tariff
          @company res
          console.log @company(), res.name, res.tariff

$ ->
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(),document.getElementById("company-info"))
```

**Source Code: View**

```
     <ul id="company-info" class="unstyled company-info">
        <li data-bind="text: company.contract"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: company.name"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: companyBalance"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: companyTariff"></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `company` property is observable, not its properties.  Since you bind directly to the properties, you will not see any changes when the company object changes.

You may be able to get away with just making use of the `with` binding.  When the company changes, the contents should update.

```
<ul id="company-info" class="unstyled company-info">
    <!-- ko with: company -->
        <li data-bind="text: contract"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li data-bind="text: companyBalance"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: companyTariff"></li>
</ul>
```

If you need to nest any other properties, you'll have to change it so the properties are actually observable.

Comment: You'll also have to update the `companyTariff` and `companyBalance` computed observables as well to read the company, then read the appropriate properties. However I don't understand coffeescript to be able to write that (it looks close enough to javascript that I understand what it is doing, not enough for me to be able to write it myself).